# How to put a scroll to bottom fields in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

Hi have spent days on this issue,But still I am not getting exact solution.

In my Layout I have "Header and Footer".In header I am displaying my layout title and in footer I am displaying AdView.I am using LinearLayout.

My xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/create_job_parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#06506D"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_newjob_rlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >       
    ....
    ...  2 buttons and one TextView
    </RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/creat_scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"        
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/creat_scrollview_child_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
       .
       .10 edittext boxes
       .
       .         
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/create_new_job_activity_adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="adunitid" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When keyboard opens and if I add "adjustResize" in manifest my entire Layout comes to top that means my adview also coming top.If I add "adjustPan" in manifest Nothing happens(Bottom fields are not scrolling).

In some docs I reed adding scrollview as a parent bottom fields also be scrolled when keyboard opens.But If I use scrollview as a parent my adview also be going to down.But I need to show adview in bottom always.How to doit.

Any one can help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a class that will be your special LinearLayout like this:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

public MyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private OnSoftKeyboardListener onSoftKeyboardListener;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec,
        final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (onSoftKeyboardListener != null) {
        final int newSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int oldSpec = getMeasuredHeight();
        if (oldSpec > newSpec) {
            onSoftKeyboardListener.onShown();
        } else {
            onSoftKeyboardListener.onHidden();
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public final void setOnSoftKeyboardListener(
        final OnSoftKeyboardListener listener) {
    this.onSoftKeyboardListener = listener;
}

public interface OnSoftKeyboardListener {
    public void onShown();

    public void onHidden();
}
```

}

now your xml layout will be like :

```
<com.example.MyLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
      android:id="@+id/create_job_parent_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#06506D"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_newjob_rlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >       

<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
/>  
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
/>  
<TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
/>  
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/creat_scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"        
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/creat_scrollview_child_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

  <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

     />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

      />     
       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"          
      />        
  </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
    <com.google.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
      android:id="@+id/create_new_job_activity_adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     app:adUnitId="adunitid">
  </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

where com.example  is package name where you have created MyLayout class.

Now in your activity where you are calling your xml layout write below code

```
 ((MyLayout)findViewById(R.id.create_job_parent_layout)).
            setOnSoftKeyboardListener(new   OnSoftKeyboardListener() {

           @Override
           public void onShown() {
                  findViewById(R.id.create_new_job_activity_adView).
                setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
           @Override
            public void onHidden() {
                findViewById(R.id.create_new_job_activity_adView).
                    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         });
```

This will surely solve your problem...

Cheers...

Comment: Thank you for giving great solution.But in this code some miner problem is there but that one is some time major one.Problem was when keyboard closing it's taking time.That means first off all keyboard closing that time in that plase black screen comes after 1 to 2 sec it will disappears.How I can resolve it?

Comment: @Rajesh I am using the same code with my project but not getting the issue as u mentioned...

Comment: Please check My Edit.I am adding screen shorts of my problem.

Comment: yes I checked ... but this is not happening with me.I'll try to reproduce once my tasks are done..

Comment: Sorry Neha.That is due to my device problem.Just know I checked in another device It's working fine.Thank you.. (:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to hide the ad view each time an `EditText` view is focused. Check if anyone is focused using `View.isFocused()`. If true, then use `AdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`.
If the none of the `editText` views is focused then show ad using `AdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.
There is no direct way for checking if a keyboard is shown on screen but there is a workaround like checking the screen size change...

Edit: This is the solution I propose...a listener for detecting any change in the size that is taken by the root view of the activity layout. The difference is calculated between the activity root view size and the active windows view size. If it is greater than 150, it is most likely a keyboard.

```
    final View ad = (View) findViewById(R.id.create_new_job_activity_adView);
    final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.create_job_parent_layout);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // calculate the difference between the root view height
                    // and the window view height
                    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                            .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                    // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    if (heightDiff > 150) {
                        ad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.i("moayad", "Keyboard is visible");
                        // keyboard is visible, do something here
                    } else {
                        ad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.i("moayad", "Keyboard is invisible");
                        // keyboard is not visible, do something here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes,Exactly like this only problem solved.But,if user clicking on edittext box and he/she done work and that time user clicking on system back button that time my edittextboxes are in focused but key board is closed.That is a problem for displaying adview.In debuging time I checked for user clicking on back key but that time onBackPressed(),onKeyDown()dispatchTouchKeyEvent() methods are not calling how can I detect user clicking on back key when keyboard open?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two mistake in the above code .. You didn't close the Parent `LinearLayout` anywhere and you have close

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_newjob_rlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >       
   </RelativeLayout>
```

without putting any content in it .. you may have made a mistake in closing it in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry,That is my mistake closing Parent layout is missing.In that relative layout I have 2 buttons and one textview.At the time of adding this all code it's giving some problem that's why I am not adding whole content.But,for my problem is not closing parent layout.can you please give me a solution.

Comment: <RelativeLayout> <ScrollView> </ScrollView><AddView android:alignParentBottom="true"> </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

The given code is to make button scrollable and I have also checked it..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                    <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnAll"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="All"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon" /> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="Bar Restaurants"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAll"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon" /> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnFashion"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="FashionBeauty"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"/> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnParty"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="PartyEntertainment"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnFashion"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"
                                  /> 
                                  <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnLife"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="Life Style"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnParty"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"
                                  /> 

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But in my code I have AdView In bottom.If I add this Adview in inside of scrollview adview also be going to be scroll.It's not good.You have any better solution for this?

Comment: why are you adding in the scrollview .                           Make a  <RelativeLayout> as Parent and add a <ScrollView> to it. and outside the<ScrollView> but inside the Relativelayout add your Addview and set Its Property alignParentBottom.